# How to dynamically pass product id from JS to Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a custom quiz. I need when a user selects two flavors of a product, then he will see a button for selecting the quantity and "Add to cart" of a double product with such flavors, which is in the admin panel. I have the functionality of selecting the desired double product.

The problem is that I need to pass a variable with the product ID from JS to Liquid in order to continue doing the desired functionality. How can I do this?

```js
  function showOrderDetails() {
    if (singleProduct1 && singleProduct2) {
      let products = {{ collections['Bundles'].products | json }};
      for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        let title = products[i].title;
        let id = products[i].id;
        let productsInBundle = title.split(" & ");
        let cleanedProductsTitle = productsInBundle.map(product => {
          return product.split("--")[0].replace("Bundle", "").trim();
        });

         if (
          cleanedProductsTitle.includes(singleProduct1.trim()) &&
          cleanedProductsTitle.includes(singleProduct2.trim())
        ) {
          bundleProduct = title;
          bundleProductId = id; //The value of this variable I need to pass to Liquid
          console.log(bundleProductId);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<div id="order-details" class="popup-content__order-details hidden">
        <div class="quantity-cart__actions">
          {% assign desired_product_id = //HERE I NEED PASS ID FROM JS %}
          {% for product in collections.bundles.products %}
            {% if product.id == desired_product_id %}
              <p>Product Name: {{ product.title }}</p>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Liquid is server side, you cannot pass a variable from js to liquid without a rendering. 
One other option is to call the ajax api and require a specific section.

Comment: Can this be done with AJAX?

Comment: You can use this api https://shopify.dev/docs/api/section-rendering